# Run linear models by group over list of variables in R

Tags: r, lapply, lm

I have a data frame and I need to run 6 2-variable linear models for each group 'site'.  Then, I need to convert the results to a data frame. The second variable in the linear model changes. I have that part down using `lapply()`, but I can't figure out how to run by groups. I've found answers on SO that answer parts of my question, but I can't figure out how to put it all together.

Here's some data:

```
structure(list(SiteName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("bp10", "bp12"), class = "factor"), 
    DMWT = c(13.9697916666667, 13.9125, 14.2152083333333, 14.7810416666667, 
    15.1541666666667, 15.7535416666667, 17.3254166666667, 18.4872916666667, 
    20.0564583333333, 21.0595833333333, 21.3925), DMAT = c(16.6714631359947, 
    18.474493439025, 20.9517661662977, 23.7017661662978, 25.5957055602372, 
    20.9688840743375, 23.7188840743375, 25.6128234682769, 27.5143386197921, 
    27.6279749834285, 26.1355507410042), ADD = c(0, 0, 0, 1.90367965367967, 
    5.70129870129876, 0, 1.90367965367967, 5.70129870129876, 
    11.400432900433, 17.2132034632037, 21.53354978355), Air200 = c(7.3229782875097, 
    7.40616010569152, 7.50025101478243, 7.63384949963092, 7.78642525720668, 
    7.51736892282216, 7.65096740767065, 7.80354316524641, 7.97854316524641, 
    8.14729316524641, 8.29592952888278), Air100 = c(15.2711601056916, 
    15.362599499631, 15.512902529934, 15.727296469328, 15.9717661662977, 
    15.5300204379738, 15.7444143773677, 15.9888840743374, 16.2306264985798, 
    16.4472174076707, 16.6433537713071), Air75 = c(16.8986348531664, 
    17.0426752572068, 17.1927762673078, 17.3687358632674, 17.5567156612472, 
    17.2098941753475, 17.3858537713071, 17.5738335692869, 17.7820153874687, 
    18.0100961955496, 18.2532275086809), Air50 = c(19.5072207117523, 
    19.6340388935705, 19.7382813178129, 19.8887358632674, 20.1060085905402, 
    19.7553992258526, 19.9058537713072, 20.1231264985799, 20.4400961955496, 
    20.7669143773678, 20.9841871046405), Air10 = c(21.9214631359947, 
    21.5850994996311, 21.2563116208432, 21.1714631359947, 21.4502510147826, 
    21.2734295288829, 21.1885810440344, 21.4673689228223, 21.9696416500951, 
    22.3779749834284, 22.5476719531254)), .Names = c("SiteName", 
"DMWT", "DMAT", "ADD", "Air200", "Air100", "Air75", "Air50", 
"Air10"), row.names = c(547L, 548L, 549L, 550L, 551L, 1593L, 
1594L, 1595L, 1596L, 1597L, 1598L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's the code for using each variable in a model.  How do I use the sites?:

```
siteslist <- unique(d$SiteName) 
varlist <- names(d)[4:9]
models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {  # apply the modeling function to our list of air variables
  lm(substitute(DMWT ~ DMAT + i, list(i = as.name(x))), data = d)  # linear model with air variable substituted
})
```

Then get model results & convert to a data frame:

```
library(relaimpo)
sumfun <- function(x) c(coef(x),
                        summary(x)$adj.r.squared,
                        sqrt(mean(resid(x)^2,na.rm=TRUE)),
                        calc.relimp(x,type="betasq")$betasq[1],
                        calc.relimp(x,type="betasq")$betasq[2],
                        calc.relimp(x,type="pratt")$pratt[1],
                        calc.relimp(x,type="pratt")$pratt[2])
mod.df <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(models,sumfun)))
```

Also tried combining variables and sites to do something like this:

```
siteslist <- unique(d$SiteName)                              
varlist <- names(d)[4:9]
sets <- expand.grid(SiteName = siteslist, Var = varlist)
models <- lapply(1:nrow(sets), function(x) {  # apply the modeling function to our list of air variables
  lm(substitute(DMWT ~ DMAT + i, list(i = as.name(sets$Var[x]))), data = d[d$SiteName ==  sets$SiteName[x],])  # linear model with air variable substituted
})
```

...but I get an error `"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '1' not found"`

Comment: Take a subset of your data for one site only. Turn your working code into a function `fit_one_site` that depends on only the input `dat` and returns whatever you want (maybe a list with the models and the data frame? Maybe just the data frame?). Then you can `lapply(split(d, d$SiteName), FUN = fit_one_site)` to get your results.

Comment: OK @Gregor.  I think that works for the modeling part.  Now, how can I use a version of my sumfun to pull out the model results? `mod.df <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(models,sumfun)))` gives me the error `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

Comment: This is what @Gregor suggested: `fit_one_site <- function(x){
  lapply(varlist, function(x) {  
  lm(substitute(DMWT ~ DMAT + i, list(i = as.name(x))), data = d) 
})
}
models <- lapply(split(d, d$SiteName), FUN = fit_one_site)`

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether you want the output for a single site to include both the model objects *and* the `sumfun` result, or just the `sumfun` result. Either way, make the `fit_one_site` function return what you want. It can `return(lapply(model_list, sumfun))` or it can `return(list(model_list, mod.df = lapply(model_list, sumfun)))`.

Comment: Just the `sumfun` result is fine. Forgive my daftness, but I'm rather new to function writing syntax.  Could you show where exact your `return...` line would go in the `fit_one_site` function? Where does `model_list` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Note this is untested as I haven't installed `relaimpo`. I'm really just re-packaging your code.

The general method is 
1. develop a function that works on one group
2. use `split` to divide your data into groups
3. use `lapply` to apply the function to each group
4. (if needed) combine the results together

### First test on a one-site subset of data:

The only changes I made are (a) to pull out a subset of data for one site and name it `one_site`. (b) to use `one_site` in your modeling code. (c) I prefer pasting a formula together as a string to using `substitute`, so I made that change. (d) White space and formatting for readability (mostly using RStudio's "reformat code").

```
## set up
varlist <- names(d)[4:9]
library(relaimpo)
sumfun <- function(x) {
    c(
        coef(x),
        summary(x)$adj.r.squared,
        sqrt(mean(resid(x) ^ 2, na.rm = TRUE)),
        calc.relimp(x, type = "betasq")$betasq[1],
        calc.relimp(x, type = "betasq")$betasq[2],
        calc.relimp(x, type = "pratt")$pratt[1],
        calc.relimp(x, type = "pratt")$pratt[2]
    )
}

## Testing: this works for one_site
one_site <- subset(d, SiteName == "bp10")

models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {  # apply the modeling function to our list of air variables
    form <- as.formula(sprintf("DMWT ~ DMAT + %s", x))
    lm(form, data = one_site)  # linear model with air variable substituted
})

## desired result
mod.df <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(models, sumfun)))
```

### Turn it into a function

Once you have code that works for a single site, we turn it into a function. The only inputs seem to be the data for one site and the variables in `varlist`. Instead of assigning the result at the bottom, we `return` it:

```
fit_one_site = function(one_site, varlist) {
    models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
            # apply the modeling function to our list of air variables
            form = as.formula(sprintf("DMWT ~ DMAT + %s", x))
            lm(form, data = one_site)  # linear model with air variable substituted
    })
    return(as.data.frame(t(sapply(models, sumfun))))
}
```

Now we can use `split` to split your data up by `SiteName`, and `lapply` to apply the `fit_one_site` function to each piece.

```
results = lapply(split(d, d$SiteName), FUN = fit_one_site, varlist = names(d)[4:9])
```

The results should be list of data frames, one for each site. If you want to combine them into one data frame, see the relevant part of my answer [at the list of data frames R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17499013/9030610).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are trying to do, but the data.table `plyr` package allows you to run models split by multiple variables. Below is an example, with `var1` and `var2` simply representing two variables you want each combination of values to be modeled separately.

```
#load packages
library(data.table)
library(plyr)

#break up by variables, then fit the model to each piece
models <- dlply(data, c("var1","var2"),
              function(data)
                lm(DV ~ 
                     IV1 + IV2
                   , data = data, weights = weights))
#apply coef to eah model and return a df
models_coef <- ldply(models, coef)
#print summary
l_ply(models_coef, summary, .print = T)
```

Comment: I need to split a data frame by groups, then on each group run models that would substitute in a different variable in the `"IV2"` position.  Don't think this will tackle the group problem.